# Pebble JavaScript Multiple JS Files (Pebble.js)

Tags: pebble-watch, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I'm creating a project on CloudPebble using JavaScript.

I have a "Constants.js" which hosts a variable that I would like to access using "app.js", which is the main contents of the app. However, running the app I receive the following error:

```
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: JavaScript Error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here is my code:

**Constants.js**

```
var mainMenuOptions = ["MenuOption1", "MenuOption2", "MenuOption3"];
```

**app.js**

```
var UI = require('ui');
var Vector2 = require('vector2');
var constants = require('Constants.js');

var mainMenu = new UI.Menu({
});

for (var i = 0; i < constants.mainMenuOptions.length; i++) { //Error occurs here
  mainMenu.item(0, i, { title: constants.mainMenuOptions[i] });
}
...
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive your `Constants.js` should have this format:

```
var Constants = {
   mainMenuOptions: ["MenuOption1", "MenuOption2", "MenuOption3"]
};

this.exports = Constants;
```

And then in `app.js` do

```
var constants = require('Constants');
```

to access it.

Used this approach in my very first Pebble.js app [Autoinsult](http://codecorner.galanter.net/2014/10/24/developing-first-pebble-js-app/) and it worked.

Comment: Thanks so much, Yuriy. Great tutorial you wrote with Autoinsult, thanks for that too - gonna definitely check out your site.